# Length and subsetting by multiple conditions

Tags: r, rstudio

So I have this data set in Excel (two column names are `Col1` and `Col2`)
`Col1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,9)` (are numbers of different sellers (**and must be duplicated**) and `Col2` which consist of names and this names are assigned to these numbers so

```
1=Mazda
2=BWM
3=Opel
4=Citroen
5=Fiat
6=Porsche
7=Audi
8=Dacia
9=Lexus
```

So now I would like to find out `unique` `length` of seller 1 by `subsetting`.

I have tried this

```
length(subset(data.set, Col2 == "Mazda"))
```

but this gave me length of Mazda and I need to find out `length` of `Col1 by Col2=Mazda`

I am missing something here:

```
length(unique(subset(data.set, Col2 == "Mazda" & ......)))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and expected result based on that..  Try `table(data.set)`

Comment: I need length for example I can se form my excel that mazda has 10 different sellers. And I need that number. So I need length which is based on two conditions Col2="Mazda" and Col1=sum of 1.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, a reproducible example with expected result would make it easy for others to test

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(df1)[,.N, list(Col1, Col2)]`

Comment: As result I need just length so i need number to implement it. So If we are looking ot my example I can see 10 sellers, but how to get that number by to conditions, I would like to do it with subsetting

Answer (score 1):

can't really figure out what you need but I'm sure `filter` from `dplyr` will suit your needs

```
filter(df, col2 == "Mazda", col1 == "10")
```